# Mailchimp background-size cover

Tags: html, css, mailchimp, background-size

I tried to make a background image cover in many different ways but Mailchimp seems to delete that piece of code.

Any approach on how to make this work.

Cheers,
Michael

Comment: When you say it deletes it, at what point do you notice it? Is it after sending a test mail, or is it after just click Next?? As a number of email clients do not support it, which could be the issue and explain why it is being removed.

Answer (score 2):

Ah Mailchimp. Well, in custom templates the best thing to do is literally DO IT ALL. Meaning, add it to the table or TD with CSS AND the default table styling.

Also you have to take into account the Outlook users that your email will go to.

SO you have to add a few things.

Let's start with the `html` tag above the `head`. First off, the best doctype to use is XHTML 1.0 transitional. Now I know that you CAN do one with an empty html tag and NO DOCTYPE, but you aren't doing yourself any favors.

Change `<html>` to `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">`

This is going to say "You are using Microsoft. Okay, where are those rules?"

Next off, in the `CSS` you need to add this:

```
#outlook a{
        padding:0;
    }
    .ReadMsgBody{
        width:100%;
    }
    body{
        width:100% !important;
        min-width:100%;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;
        -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    }
    .ExternalClass{
        width:100%;
    }
    v*{
        behavior:url(#default#VML);
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

Pay attention to the ones like `v*` and `#outlook a`.

SO you have those, and now you can add in the stuff for the background. In **EACH** table or td that you want a background, you have to add it inline. **BUT** it is a good practice to ALSO use an `xlmns` wrapper. This doesn't have to be code, it can be commented out and will still be read as a backup.

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
  <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
  <v:fill type="tile" src="YOURIMAGEPATH.jpg" color="#000000"/>
  </v:background>
  <![endif]-->

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" bgcolor="#000000" background="YOURIMAGEPATH.jpg" style="background-image:url(YOURIMAGEPATH.jpg)">
     <tr>
         <td align="center">
            <!--YOUR CONTENT-->
         </td>
     </tr>
</table>

<!--[if gte mso 9]>
   </v:textbox>
   </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

Notice how the entire table is wrapped in that commented section? That says that basically if your recipient is using Outlook, it is going to go ahead and render the background.

Campaign Monitor made a really nifty too to do just this to `table` and `td`. Remember too that you can NOT use `cover` or skew the background at all. Just make it the 100% size your email will be.

```
<!--Hopefully not more than 600px-->
```

[Backgrounds.cm by Campaign Monitor](https://backgrounds.cm/)